# Compare 2 columns and select the same name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare 2 particular columns and select the particular data from my dataframe. For example,

```
>>>df   
c1    c2  c3    c4     c5  c6
David 23  0.5   Jason  34  0.9
Lisa  20  0.2   Gill   32  0.6
Mary  12  0.7   Lisa   22  0.12       # my dataframe
Damen 58  0.17  David  48  0.94
```

I wish I can get the same person from c1 and c4 column, which means the person who both exists in c1 and c4. That is Lisa and David. Then I can see something like below in my result.

```
>>>result
c1    c2  c3   c4     c5  c6
David 23  0.5  David  48  0.94
Lisa  20  0.2  Lisa   22  0.12       # I need Lisa and David only.
```

I have tried something like:

```
df['c1'].map(lambda x: x == df['c4'])

df[[x == df['c4'] for x in df['c1']]]
```

But I only get the same line based on c1 of David and Lisa:

```
>>>result
c1    c2  c3    c4     c5  c6
David 23  0.5   Jason  34  0.9     
Lisa  20  0.2   Gill   32  0.6     # I do not need Gill and Jason!!!
```

Does anyone know how could I revise my command by using pandas, thanks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[['c1','c2','c3']].merge(df[['c4','c5','c6']], left_on='c1', right_on='c4')
```

From your input yields

```
      c1  c2   c3     c4  c5    c6
0  David  23  0.5  David  48  0.94
1   Lisa  20  0.2   Lisa  22  0.12
```

Comment: Hi there, if I'd like to add a filter step before my question, for example, the value in c2 and c5 are must less or equal 22, then I can only get Lisa in my question, I tried `df[(df['c2']=< 22.0) & (df['c5']=< 22.0)]` , but it cannot work, do you know why?

Comment: What happens if you use "<=" instead of "=<"?